# How to use whereBetween for dates in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to get the number of new users for each week using the `created_at` column. I am trying to use the `whereBetween`syntax but it always return `0` even when it is suppose to return otherwise.

```
{{ DB::table('users')
                ->whereBetween('created_at', array(date("Y/m/d h:i:s", strtotime('sunday last week')), date("Y/m/d h:i:s", strtotime('saturday this week'))))->count(); }}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query itself should work as written, though you might want to verify that `created_at` is a column of either `timestamp`, `date`, or `datetime` type. When you created the users table, did you use a migration to create your users table, and if so, did you specify `$table->timestamps();`? Or did you manually define the `created_at` column, and perhaps set it to a string?

A couple other (unrelated) suggestions:

• It appears that you're running this query in a view, echoing the count using blade. This logic would be better handled elsewhere, perhaps in your User model, and the result passed to the view by the controller.

• You can simplify your query using PHPs DateTime object, replacing your `date(...strtotime...)` with `date_create(...)`:

```
$usersThisWeek = User::whereBetween(
    'created_at', array(
        date_create('sunday last week'), 
        date_create('saturday this week')
    ))->count();
```

Comment: Yes, the query executes but I am not getting the required output. The `created_at` column is a `timestamp` type. Changing the `date(...strtotime...)` to `date_create` did the magic. Thanks